# Is it true that 2 spaces are homeomorphic iff the spaces without a point are?

Tags: general-topology

I've seen some problems in wich they use this trick to show two spaces are not homeomorphic: they take out a point and some topological invariant does not conserve, so they conclude that the original spaces are not homeomorphic. So I wonder if it is a well-know theorem, how can I prove it?

> $f: (X,\tau) \rightarrow  (Y,\tau')$ is a homeomorfism if and only if $f: (X-\{P\},\tau) \rightarrow  (Y-f(\{P\}),\tau')$ is a homeomorfism, independently of f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This theorem is an "only if", not an "if and only if".

If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, and we set $X' = X-\{P\}$ and $Y' = Y - \{f(P)\}$, then the induced function $f':X'\to Y'$ is a homeomorphism. Here is a proof:

> It's easy to see that $f'$ is a well-defined function, and that it's bijective and continuous. It remains to show that it takes open sets to open sets. Now, take an arbitrary open subset $U'\subseteq X'$. By definition of subset topology, there is an open $U\subseteq X$ such that $U\cap X' = U'$. Thus $V = f(U)$ is open in $Y$ by homeomorphicity of $f$. Thus $V' = V\cap Y'$ is an open subset of $Y'$, by definition of subspace topology. Finally, we note that $V' = f'(U')$, showing that $f'$ takes open sets to open sets, which makes it a homeomorphism.

Note that nothing here depends on $P$ being a point. It can be any subset of $X$. Some choices of subspaces are more useful than others, though.

However, the converse is not necessarily true. For instance, take $X$ to be the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ (with the standard topology) and $Y$ to be the unit circle $\left\{e^{it}\mid t\in [0, 2\pi)\right\}\subseteq \Bbb C$ (with the standard topology). Then the function $f:X\to Y$ defined by $f(x) = e^{ix}$ is not a homeomorphism. However, if we set $P = 0$, then the restricted $f'$ as described above *does* become a homeomorphism: An open interval is homeomorphic to a circle that's missing a point.

Comment: What do you mean by well-defined function? and how to prove it is bijective and continuous? Could you detail how to get the last part $V'=f '(U')$, i don't see it.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver I have given you a framework on which to build the full proof. I really do advice you to try to fill in the remaining cracks yourelf. How are you going to grok topology if all you ever do is read other people's solutions and proofs? You have to practice working with functions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be proved, since it is not true. On $[0,1]$ consider the usual topology. Consider also the topology induced by the distance $d$ defined by$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}\lvert x-y\rvert&\text{ if }x,y\in[0,1)\text{ or }x=y=1\\\lvert x-2\rvert&\text{ if }x<1\text{ and }y=1\\\lvert y-2\rvert&\text{ if }x=1\text{ and }y<1.\end{cases}$$Then $[0,1)$ with the usual topology and $[0,1)$ with the new topolgy are homeomorphic, but this is not true anymore if you put the number $1$ back.